# Oscillation of the Drain-Source voltage in flyback converter

Tags: circuit-analysis, switch-mode-power-supply

The image below describes a flyback converter with a clamping circuit off and the leakage inductor is reset, so the clamping diode is off (blocking):

[image]

My question is about the resonant frequency.

The title of the image and the formula given in this page for the frequency of the oscillation includes only the leakage inductance and the lump capacitor. what about the primary inductance, **why does not this inductance contribute in the frequency of oscillation of the drain voltage at this moment?**

Comment: Learn Design are we done here? Did you understand the answer?

Answer (score 4):

> *why does not this inductance contribute in the frequency of
> oscillation of the Drain-Voltage at this moment ?*

**Fact** - The magnetization inductance + the leakage inductance = total primary inductance.

**Fact** - The magnetization inductance 100% couples to the secondary

Due to the 100% coupling, magnetization inductance transfers 100% of its energy to the secondary leaving only the energy in the primary leakage inductance to be problematic to the primary MOSFET/switch.

In effect, the magnetization inductance is "clamped" by the secondary voltage and, given that in that part of the switching cycle the secondary voltage is fixed, the magnetization inductance voltage also becomes fixed and cannot contribute to primary voltage oscillation. It cannot contribute because in effect, it becomes a voltage source.